# Trying to save the workspace, but get an "Access is denied" error

Tags: r, save

I'm very new to R and this is my first post here.

I'm using Rstudio (Version 1.4.1717; R version 4.1.0) and am trying to save my workspace image to a file.

I'm using this code:

```
save.image("C:/Users/../Documents")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in save.image("C:/Users/../Documents") : 
  image could not be renamed and is left in C:/Users/../DocumentsTmp1
In addition: Warning message:
In file.rename(outfile, file) :
  cannot rename file 'C:/Users/../DocumentsTmp1' to 'C:/Users/../Documents', reason 'Access is denied'
```

The "DocumentsTmp1" file is created in "C:/Users/..", but it seems it can't subsequently be renamed and stored in the "C:/Users/../Documents" file.

I've tried running Rstudio as Administrator, but this didn't help. I am able to save files to the specified file using the Windows file explorer. I've also tried saving to a different file but get the same error. I hope someone can help!

Comment: You've specified a file path but no file name.

Comment: You're right, thanks! 

I can now save a .RData file with the following code:

`save.image("C:/Users/jlzpo/Documents/Workspace1.RData")`

However, when I open this file all it seems to contain is a script file with ". ? ." . I was hoping it would load my objects as well. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It should contain everything that was in your global workspace.  How are you opening it? `load("C:/Users/jlzpo/Documents/Workspace1.RData")`?

Comment: Yes it's working now. I think I mixed up the .RData suffix. Thanks a bunch!